# Backbone.syphon infinite loop?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

I'm trying to use Backbone.syphon like so:

```
var WhoChoiceView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: template,
    model: Model,

    events:{
        'click #start_add_person': 'addPerson'
    },

    addPerson: function(){
        var data = Syphon.serialize(this);
        this.model.set(data);

        this.model.save();

    }
});
```

The use of syphon should be limited to the button click event, but I get this error when I'm showing views:

```
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

(anonymous function)
forEach
Backbone.Syphon.flattenData
Backbone.Syphon.flattenData
(anonymous function)
forEach ...`
```

There were no line numbers on this part of the stacktrace.  The last two line of my code were:

```
        console.log('app:show:content');

        App.content.show(view);         // I'm using marionette(App) and ItemView
```

I'm not sure how the flattenData method is called.  Has anyone seen this behavior?

I'm using Backbone.Syphon, v0.4.1

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I ran it again and it is doing the same thing.  Although when Firefox gave me the option to kill the script it was at backbone.syphon line 283:                _.extend(flatData, hash);

Comment: I am calling Syphon from somewhere else:      Syphon.deserialize(view, view["model"]);

Comment: code you show above looks to be OK. I suspect it is somewhere else - perhaps the place where you create view instance? Check module initializers for bad method references.

Comment: I commented the deserialize call and all is well.  I think I may of had some circular structure in my relational setup and it couldn't flatten out the circle.  I'm pulling backbone-relational.  I submit my object tree at the end of a wizard. I can model my "has many" with collections of ItemViews that have collections of models.